# docker exec pg_dump in bash function

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, pg-dump

I'm trying to run `pg_dump` in a docker container, in a bash function, but I'm getting an error `can't create : nonexistent directory`. The dir does exist, so I suspect that the output redirection (>) is trying to run on the host system when running inside the function.  When I run the command outside of the bash function it works.

Note that the psql container has the directory `/var/lib/postgresql/backups/` mapped to `/usr/share/postgresql/backups/` on the host.

**The command that works is**,

`docker exec -it psql sh -c 'pg_dump -U $PG_USER MY_TABLE > /var/lib/postgresql/backups/my_table.sql`

**The function that is not working**

```
# @param $1 -- the name of the table to export
# @param $2 -- the filename to export the table to
function backup_table() {
  local table_name="$1"
  local output_path="/var/lib/postgresql/backups/$2"
  docker exec -it psql sh -c 'pg_dump -U "$PG_USER" $table_name > $output_path'
}
backup_table MY_TABLE my_table.sql
```

Comment: Variables aren't expanded in single quotes.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't actually want the backup file to be in the container temporary filesystem.  Would it make more sense to run `pg_dump` directly on the host, connecting to the database container's published ports?  That would remove the `docker exec`, the `sh -c` wrapper, and a layer of quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection is properly happening inside the container -- but `output_path` isn't being passed there.

---

Assuming `PG_USER` is defined inside the container:

```
backup_table() {                    # POSIX function syntax
  local table_name output_path cmd  # declare all our locals at once
  table_name="$1"
  output_path="/var/lib/postgresql/backups/$2"

  # Bash extension, compatible through older releases: substitute
  # escaped values in place of %q placeholders into $cmd
  printf -v cmd 'pg_dump -U "$PG_USER" %q >%q' "$table_name" "$output_path"
  docker exec -it psql bash -c "$cmd"
}
backup_table MY_TABLE my_table.sql
```

Note:

- We're using POSIX-compliant function declaration syntax, not the widely-incompatible bastardization of ksh `function backup_table {` and POSIX `backup_table() {` previously in use.
- We're using `printf %q` to escape variables before substituting them into shell syntax, to ensure that the remote shell parses the content back to their original values.
- We're using `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`, because `printf %q` only guarantees compatibility with the same shell (so ksh's `printf %q` generates code that ksh is guaranteed to parse, etc) in corner cases. (It's possible to write a helper that uses the Python `shlex` module if you need to generate escapings compatible with all POSIX shells, but arguably out-of-scope here).
- Declaring locals ahead-of-time is good form, because `local var=$(somecommand)` returns the exit status of `local`, not that of `somecommand`; being in the habit of separating `local var` from actual assignment to `var` avoids the pitfall.

If you only need to support bash 5.0 or newer, you could replace the printf command with:

```
cmd='pg_dump -U "$PG_USER" '"${table_name@Q}"' >'"${output_path@Q}"
```